# How to delete all implicit (default) methods of class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, methods, default

C++ compiler in certain conditions for class adds implicit default constructor, copy constructor, destructor, conversion operators, assignment operators, etc. And other implicit methods.

How do I disable/delete all possible implicit methods in shortest way possible?

I don't want my class to be un-copyable, I want just these default methods to be disabled so that compiler throws compile error and I implement them by myself. I just want to have over-control, so that compiler doesn't do any silent work about my class.

For example I can do next thing (this is just a dummy example, in real life I can have any complex class):

```
class C {
private:
    C() = delete;
    C(C const & other) = delete;
    C & operator = (C const & other) = delete;
};
```

But this is long way, also I can forget deleting some of methods signatures and I need to delete all of them. So that I reimplement all methods from scratch by myself.

And I need to see errors for all methods that other code needs/uses and that I have not yet implemented, instead of compiler silently implementing those methods for me.

Also if I delete default methods like I did above in my example, how can I be sure that there are no other silently created methods? Is there online a list of 100% all standard methods created silently by compiler?

Comment: _default constructor, copy constructor, destructor, assignment operators_ OK. But _conversion operators, comparison operators, etc._? Which do you mean? (Something I'm not aware of? Your exposed `class C`doesn't have a base class. So, there is nothing what could be inherited.)

Comment: @Scheff Maybe I mistaken, I thought that compiler sometimes implements `==` operator, no? If not I'll correct my post, just tell me. Also I just meant that compiler may implement different things silently. It doesn't matter for me which concrete methods it implements. I just want to disable all of them.

Comment: _I thought that compiler sometimes implements == operator, no?_ No. [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e4047a0b17cb243)

Comment: The only implicit conversion of custom classes, I'm aware of, is the conversion from derived to base class. But, your `class C` doesn't have a base class.

Comment: "I need to delete all of them." Why? you want your class to be unusable?

Comment: @Scheff I gave just an example of `class C`. In real life I may derive also. I need some universal way to solve my task. Including conversion to derived class. Any silently done code regarding my class should be stopped. But right now conversion to base class is not of that importance, but still will be interesting to solve.

Comment: @Caleth I want such class that I will define everything from scratch by myself. If it does silently something then I want to do this only explicitly by implementing my own methods. That example above `class C` is only a dummy example. In real life I'll have a rich class.

Comment: "I want such class that I will define everything from scratch by myself", still, why?

Comment: @Caleth Because it happened to me several times already that compiler was silently doing something about my class, something that was logical by default to compiler. But this default behaviour was totally wrong for my particular class. And I found that wrong behaviour of usage only when I debugged a user program. I want to prevent such unwanted "default" behaviour for some classes.

Comment: The more common way is to follow the rule of zero. User code doesn't need to define *any* of the special members

Comment: @Caleth Just one very common example of misuse is following - if I forget to delete or implement my copy constructor then user by default may try to copy my class. And my class may be unsuitable for copying and program crash may appear (or even worse silently doing something without crash). If compiler informed me (through compile error) that user tried to use copy constructor then I will just implement this method whenever user used it for the first time. If compiler informs me about all such cases then I can develop my class on-demand, whenever new use-case is found by me or somebody else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228465/discussion-between-caleth-and-arty).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may go for a mixin approach. Define the cumbersome class once

```
class DeleteAllSpecialMemebers {
private:
    DeleteAllSpecialMemebers() = delete;
    DeleteAllSpecialMemebers(DeleteAllSpecialMemebers const &) = delete;
    DeleteAllSpecialMemebers & operator = (DeleteAllSpecialMemebers const &) = delete;
    DeleteAllSpecialMemebers(DeleteAllSpecialMemebers &&) = delete;
    DeleteAllSpecialMemebers & operator = (DeleteAllSpecialMemebers &&) = delete;
protected:
    struct token { explicit token() = default; };
    DeleteAllSpecialMemebers(token) {}
};
```

Then inherit from it:

```
class C : private DeleteAllSpecialMemebers{
public:
    C(int) : DeleteAllSpecialMemebers(token{}) {}
};
```

The extra `token` type is to allow deriving classes to implement *other* constructors, such as `C::C(int)` (or even a user-provided `C::C()`).

[See it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VVk0EPXI0zu7Gq88).

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that this is the full list and nothing else is implemented by default? For example you forgot destructor. Can I see somewhere online the full list of all possible implicit methods created by compiler silently?

Comment: @Arty - I did not forget the destructor. It's not as useful to delete it as it is other members. Stopping destruction has little merit. But if you want, you can update the mixin class to delete it too, and all other classes will pick up the update.

Comment: Why delete the move constructors? They disappear automatically when the copy is deleted.

Comment: @rustyx - [Kate Gregory said it best](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYVxGyido9g).

Comment: I don't need to stop class from being destructed. I just want from compiler to throw compile error on anything that is not defined by me. For example I may forget creating my own destructor, and if compiler tells me about it then I can start thinking of things that may be needed inside my destructor. I just want to ensure that no code is applied to my object silently.

Comment: @Arty - If you delete the destructor, there is *no way* to unring that bell in a derived class. There is only ever *one* destructor for a class, and all deriving classes must invoke it.

Comment: @Arty actually the list is more than complete. I suppose it explicitly deletes all only for the sake of clarity. For example no move assignment is implcitly defined when the class has a user declared copy constructor

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 BTW, a bit offtopic, I saw your username several times already on StackOverflow and always wanted to ask. Can you tell me what is it about 463035818? How can it be prime? Is it a kind of special number?

Comment: @Arty 463035818 is neither prime, nor particularly large. I assume that's the joke

Comment: @Arty offtopic yes, though as you ask... My original username had 303 in it. I decided to change my username and used a rng to get some random id, on the first roll the random number did contain 303. Since then I always keep that id when I change my username.

Comment: @Caleth the "joke" was that there is no largest prime, for some reason I only get complaints about the value ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 tobi303 according to this https://web.archive.org/web/20141221201812/http://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/tobi303

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica If you know, can you also point me to some place online that states that only this list of your methods defined in standard compiler by default and nothing else? I want to be 100% sure that there are no other methods. Is it stated anywhere in online documentation?

Comment: @Arty - C++ is designed by committee and specified in an official ISO publication. The standard itself is copyrighted and costs money. But the committee is allowed to (and does) make its drafts freely available online. Here it is, from the last (pre-publication) C++20 draft: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class#special-1.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for precise online link. Accepted+UpVoted your answer. Would be nice if you put this link into your answer as it was part of my question to point out to online doc if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest option might be to have a reusable dummy base class:

```
struct NoSpecialMember {
    NoSpecialMember(const NoSpecialMember&) = delete;
    NoSpecialMember& operator=(const NoSpecialMember&) = delete;
    NoSpecialMember(NoSpecialMember&&) = delete;
    NoSpecialMember& operator=(NoSpecialMember&&) = delete;
    ~NoSpecialMember() = default;
};
```

It's sufficient to inherit `private`ly;

```
class Test : private NoSpecialMember {};
```

with the following result:

```
static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<Test>);
static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<Test>);
static_assert(!std::is_move_constructible_v<Test>);
static_assert(!std::is_move_assignable_v<Test>);
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I be sure that this list of deleted methods is complete? That there is not a single other method implemented silently? Is it stated somewhere that this list of methods is all that compiler does and nothing else?

Comment: Probably you also forgot default constructor. It is also one of methods created silently in some situations.

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed generated. However, it's also a useful one for a base class, as you can simply inherit from it without doing anything special about its initialization (see StoryTeller's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Define helper and use it as field of class where it should be disabled:

```cpp
struct DisableCopyAssign
{
    DisableCopyAssign(char){}
    DisableCopyAssign(const DisableCopyAssign&) = delete;
    DisableCopyAssign(DisableCopyAssign&&) = delete;
};

class Foo
{
private:
    DisableCopyAssign dummy;
};
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ce8sjq

Comment: Probably your solution makes class uncopyable. But I don't want to deny copying. I just want to take over-control of my class. I want to explicitly define all operations instead of compiler defining them for me silently. I just want compiler to throw compile error when something is used but not implemented by me. For example if I forgot to implement copy constructor - I want compiler to throw compile error and then I implement my own copy constructor, after that my class becomes copyable.

Comment: No problem this just disables default implementations. You can define manually required functionality. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c3MobW

Comment: Philosophy is exactly same as accepted answer. Small difference is there inheritance is used here field (for compiler there is no difference).

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Nice variant, UpVoting! For me it looks also nice when not doing inheritance.

Comment: There is a slight class [size issue](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Eja7b3) with this approach. It has to do with the fact that sizeof(anything) is > 0.